# CCS/RF430FRL152HEVM: Trouble NFC value reading for RF430FRL152H

Tags: texas-instruments, nfc, ti-ccstudio

I am using the RF430FRL152HEVM kit for NFC communication with a mobile phone. I am building an app to read from this evaluation board and I am having trouble sending/reading an NDEF signal. I saw that there might be a compatibility issue between ISO15693 and my phone (Samsung Galaxy S10) but I don't see anywhere online where it may lead to that. I am using the code provided by texas instrument to send NDEF memory provided below. I will also provide my main activity from android studio. If anyone can tell me where the problem is that would be great. My phone can react to the NFC tag being discovered but not NDEF.
NFC Code Composer Studio CODE:

```
/*
 * main.c
 *
 * RF430FRL152H NFC Only Example Project
 *
 * Copyright (C) 2014 Texas Instruments Incorporated - http://www.ti.com/ 
 * 
 * 
 *  Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without 
 *  modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions 
 *  are met:
 *
 *    Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright 
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 *    Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the 
 *    documentation and/or other materials provided with the   
 *    distribution.
 *
 *    Neither the name of Texas Instruments Incorporated nor the names of
 *    its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *    from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 *  THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS 
 *  "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT 
 *  LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
 *  A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT 
 *  OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, 
 *  SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT 
 *  LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
 *  DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
 *  THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT 
 *  (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE 
 *  OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 *
*/
#include <msp430.h>
#include <rf430frl152h.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "types.h"

//*****************************FUNCTION PROTOTYPES********************************/
void DeviceInit(void);
void initISO15693(u16_t parameters );
//********************************************************************************/
//**********************Allocate Memory to Store ADC Reading**********************/
#define ADC_ADDRESS 0xF88C // Block 9
#pragma RETAIN(ADC_Read);
#pragma location = ADC_ADDRESS;
u16_t ADC_Read[2];
//********************************************************************************/


//*****************************DEFINES *******************************************/
#define CLEAR_BLOCK_LOCKS                               BIT3
#define FRAM_LOCK_BLOCK_AREA_SIZE                       38
#define FRAM_LOCK_BLOCKS                                0xF840  //Address of ISO15693 lock blocks


#define ROM_EUSCI_SUPPORT_ENABLED       BIT2
#define EROM_EUSCI_SUPPORT_DISABLED     0
#define ROM_SENSOR_SUPPORT_ENABLED      BIT7
#define ROM_SENSOR_SUPPORT_DISABLED     0
#define NFC_BRIDGE_DISABLED             BIT6
#define NFC_BRIDGE_ENABLED              0
#define EIGHT_BYTE_BLOCK                BIT0
#define FOUR_BYTE_BLOCK                 0
#define FIRST_ISO_PAGE                  BIT1
#define SECOND_ISO_PAGE                 0

/* Firmware System Control Byte
 *
 *     Bit 0:   ISOBlockSize                0 - 4 byte,     1 - 8 byte
 *     Bit 1:   Page                        0 - page 1,     1 - page 0 (Effective only for 4-byte block mode)
 *     Bit 2:   ROMEUSCISupportEnabled      0 - disabled,   1 - enabled (Forced to 0 on RF430FRL153H)
 *     Bit 3-5: ReservedISO
 *     Bit 6:   NFCBridgeDisable            0 - enabled,    1 - disabled (see note below)
 *     Bit 7:   ROMSensorSupportEnable      0 - disabled,   1 - enabled (Forced to 0 on RF430FRL154H)
 *
 *     NFC bridge is recommended to be disabled in this project.  Unexpected behaviour can occur,
 *     trying to use it, due to the configuration being setup here.
 *
 *     If eUSCI host controller portion is needed along with the RF functionality, the default project
 *     must be used.  That is NFC cannot be supported in that application (because the I2C/SPI host controller
 *     control registers are in the same place that the NFC file needs to be).  However the rest of the FRAM
 *     memory can be used for storing and reading using ISO15693.
 */
#define FIRMWARE_CONTROL_ADDRESS    0xF867
#pragma RETAIN(Firmware_System_Control_Byte);
#pragma location = FIRMWARE_CONTROL_ADDRESS
const u08_t Firmware_System_Control_Byte = ROM_SENSOR_SUPPORT_DISABLED + EROM_EUSCI_SUPPORT_DISABLED + NFC_BRIDGE_DISABLED + FOUR_BYTE_BLOCK + FIRST_ISO_PAGE; //0x7F,      // this value sets the firmware system control register

// ROM variables - DO NOT CHANGE !!!
// Declared to protect from use by compiler
/********************************************/
#pragma RETAIN(DS)
#pragma location = 0x1C00
u08_t DS;
#pragma RETAIN(RF)
#pragma location = 0x1C6A
const u08_t RF;
#pragma RETAIN(NRX)
#pragma location = 0x1CA4 //rx
const u08_t NRX[34];
#pragma RETAIN(NTX)
#pragma location = 0x1CC6 //tx
const u08_t NTX[33];
#pragma RETAIN(EL)
#pragma location = 0x1CF2
const u08_t EL;
#pragma RETAIN(PF)
#pragma location = 0x1C0A
const u16_t PF[48];
/********************************************/

#define NDEF_START_ADDRESS  0xF868
#pragma RETAIN(NFC_NDEF_Message);
#pragma location = NDEF_START_ADDRESS;                                                                  // the location of the address
const u08_t NFC_NDEF_Message[21] = {
        // Most of the Android applications will not recognize this message as NDEF at this point, due to the
        // tag not being registered with Android NFC stack.  However ISO15693 RFID communication is supported.
        // Block 0
        0xE1,       // NDEF Magic Number
        0x40,       // Version Number, read/write access conditions
        0xF2,//F3*4/8 = 0x79  //0x7E,       // 1008 bytes / 8 = 126 blocks
        0x00,//extended memory //0x00,      // does not support read multiple blocks (limited to only 3 blocks)

        // Block 1
        0x03,       // NDEF Message present
        0x0B,       // Length , 11 bytes
        0xD1,       // Record header
        0x01,       // type length

        // Block 2
        0x07,       // Payload length
        0x55,       // Record Type U (URI)
        0x01,       // URI header identifier
        0x74,       // 't'

        // Block 3
        0x69,       // 'i'
        0x2E,       // '.'
        0x63,       // 'c'
        0x6F,       // 'o'

        // Block 4
        0x6D,       // 'm'
        0xFE,       // TLV terminator
        0x00,       // Empty don't care
        0x00,       // Empty don't care
};

/*********************** SUMMARY **************************************************************************************************
 * This project only utilizes the RF stack (ISO15693) on the ROM of the RF430FRL15xH. This setup allows the user to make a
 * custom application that is run from FRAM.  Only the RF13M vector that runs the RF stack needs to be pointing to its
 * ROM location.
 */

/**************************************************************************************************************************************************
*   Main
***************************************************************************************************************************************************
*
* Brief :
*
* Param[in] :   None
*
*
* Param[out]:   None
*
* Return :
*
**************************************************************************************************************************************************/

void main()
{
    WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;                   // Stop watchdog
    // ROM RF13M module setup ** The following three lines are needed for proper RF stack operation
    DS = 1;                                     // ROM variable needs to be initialized here
    asm ( " CALL #0x5CDA ");                    // Call ROM function ( Initialize function pointers)
    asm ( " CALL #0x5CAC ");                    // Call ROM function ( Check part configuration)

    initISO15693(CLEAR_BLOCK_LOCKS);
    DeviceInit();

    //Setup ADC
    SD14CTL0 = SD14EN + VIRTGND + SD14IE; //ADC enabled, Virtual Ground enabled, Interrupt enabled.
    SD14CTL1 = SD14UNI + SD14INTDLY0;     // Unipolar mode, Interrupt triggered after first sample.

        while(1)
        {
             SD14CTL0 |= SD14SC; //begin conversion
            __bis_SR_register(LPM3_bits + GIE);
        }
}


/**************************************************************************************************************************************************
*  DeviceInit
***************************************************************************************************************************************************
*
* Brief : Initialize the clock system and other settings
*         Patchable function
*
* Param[in] :   parameters:  has these independent options
*                            INITIALIZE_DEVICE_CLOCK_SYSTEM - initializes the clock system
*                            POPULATE_INTERRUPT_VECTOR_IN_INITIALIZATION - populate the default interrupt vectors and recalculate their CRC
*
* Param[out]:  None
*
* Return  None
*
* Patchable :   Yes
**************************************************************************************************************************************************/
void DeviceInit(void)
{
    P1SEL0 = 0xF0; //keep JTAG
    P1SEL1 = 0xF0; //keep JTAG
    P1DIR &= ~0xEF;
    P1REN = 0;

    CCSCTL0 = CCSKEY;                        // Unlock CCS

    CCSCTL1 = 0;                             // do not half the clock speed
    CCSCTL4 = SELA_1 + SELM_0 + SELS_0;      // Select VLO for ACLK and select HFCLK/DCO for MCLK, and SMCLK
    CCSCTL5 = DIVA_2 + DIVM_1 + DIVS_1;      // Set the Dividers for ACLK (4), MCLK, and SMCLK to 1
    CCSCTL6 = XTOFF;                         // Turns of the crystal if it is not being used
    CCSCTL8 = ACLKREQEN + MCLKREQEN + SMCLKREQEN; //disable clocks if they are not being used

    CCSCTL0_H |= 0xFF;                       // Lock CCS

  return;
}

/**************************************************************************************************************************************************
*  initISO15693
***************************************************************************************************************************************************
*
* Brief : Initializes the RF Stack
*
* Param[in] :   parameter - the configuration to setup the ISO15693 (option to clear the lock blocks)
*
* Param[out]:   None
*
* Return        None
**************************************************************************************************************************************************/
void initISO15693(u16_t parameters )
{

  // enable interrupts  ** Do not change the following two lines, needed for proper RF stack operatoin
  RF13MCTL |= RF13MTXEN + RF13MRXEN + RF13MRFTOEN;  // set up rx and tx functionality on RF13M module
  RF13MINT |= RF13MRXIE + RX13MRFTOIE;              // enable interrupts on RX and on timeout and over and under flow checking

  if (parameters & CLEAR_BLOCK_LOCKS )
  {
    //initializeBlockLocks();   //inline function
    memset ((u08_t *) FRAM_LOCK_BLOCKS, 0xFF, FRAM_LOCK_BLOCK_AREA_SIZE);     //block is locked with a zero bit, clears FRAM and RAM lock blocks
  }
}


//#pragma vector = RFPMM_VECTOR
//__interrupt void RFPMM_ISR(void)
//{
//}
//
//#pragma vector = PORT1_VECTOR
//__interrupt void PORT1_ISR(void)
//{
//}
//
//#pragma vector = SD_ADC_VECTOR
//__interrupt void SD_ADC_ISR(void)
//{
//}
//
//#pragma vector = USCI_B0_VECTOR
//__interrupt void USCI_B0_ISR(void)
//{
//}
//#pragma CODE_SECTION(RF13M_ISR, ".fram_driver_code")  // comment this line for using ROM's RF13M ISR, uncomment next one, see .cmd file for details
#pragma CODE_SECTION(RF13M_ISR, ".rf13m_rom_isr")       // comment this line for creating a custom RF13M ISR that will exist in FRAM, bypassing ROM's, uncomment previous
#pragma vector = RF13M_VECTOR
__interrupt void RF13M_ISR(void)
{
    // Right now this vector is pointing to the ROMs firmware location that runs the RF stack. 
    // Entering code here will, without changing the CODE_SECTION lines
    // above, will cause an error.
    // Changing the code section above will cause the ROM RF stack to be bypassed.  New handler will need to be created.
}

//#pragma vector = WDT_VECTOR
//__interrupt void WDT_ISR(void)
//{
//}
//
//#pragma vector = TIMER0_A1_VECTOR
//__interrupt void TimerA1_ISR(void)
//{
//}
//
//#pragma vector = TIMER0_A0_VECTOR
//__interrupt void TimerA0_ISR(void)
//{
//}
//
//#pragma vector = UNMI_VECTOR
//__interrupt void UNMI_ISR(void)
//{
//}
//
//#pragma vector = SYSNMI_VECTOR
//__interrupt void SysNMI_ISR(void)
//{
//}
#pragma vector=SD_ADC_VECTOR
interrupt void ADC (void)
{
    switch(__even_in_range(SD14IV,4))
    {
        case SD14IV__NONE: // no interrupt pending
        {
            break;}

        case SD14IV__RES: //ADC Data available
        {
            SD14CTL0 &= ~SD14IFG;   //clear the data available interrupt
            ADC_Read[0] =  SD14MEM0; //Read the ADC Data
            __bic_SR_register_on_exit(LPM4_bits);
            break;}
        case SD14IV__OV: //Memory Overflow
        {
            SD14CTL0 &= ~SD14OVIFG; //clear the overflow bit
             break;}
    }
}
```

Android Studio CODE:

```
package com.example.app_2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic;
import android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Intialize attributes
    NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    final static String TAG = "nfc_test";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Initialise NfcAdapter
        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        //If no NfcAdapter, display that the device has no NFC
        if (nfcAdapter == null){
            Toast.makeText(this,"NO NFC Capabilities",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
        //Create a PendingIntent object so the Android system can
        //populate it with the details of the tag when it is scanned.
        //PendingIntent.getActivity(Context,requestcode(identifier for
        //                           intent),intent,int)
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,new Intent(this,this.getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        assert nfcAdapter != null;
        //nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(context,pendingIntent,
        //                                    intentFilterArray,
        //                                    techListsArray)
        nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this,pendingIntent,null,null);
    }
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //Onpause stop listening
        if (nfcAdapter != null) {
            nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
        resolveIntent(intent);
    }

    private void resolveIntent(Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (
               // NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                      //  || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                         NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            Tag tag = (Tag) intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            assert tag != null;
            byte[] payload = detectTagData(tag).getBytes();
            //Open the next activity
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, NFC_Info.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: did u find a solution ? cause i'm interrested

Comment: I was able to email the support team and they gave me a base code and told me how to work it. They have an example project that sends out a text in the form of "ti.com" from the NFC chip.